# springframework security cannot find UserBuilder

Tags: spring, spring-security

I cannot Import UserBuilder form SpringFramework Security and method

```
User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder();
```

I used spring springframework security v 5.0.2 RELEASE , spring-security-core 3.2.0 RELEASE , springframework version 5.0.4.RELEASE

Picture error cannot import and user method

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQJ6Q.png)

Maven

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.luv2code</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-security-demo</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>spring-security-demo</name>

<properties>
    <springframework.version>5.0.4.RELEASE</springframework.version>

    <springsecurity.version>5.0.2.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Spring MVC support -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet, JSP and JSTL support -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<!-- TO DO: Add support for Maven WAR Plugin -->

<build>
    <finalName>spring-security-demo</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugins</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using it the wrong way.
Try changing

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>${springframework.version}</version> //<--- Issue because of this
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Also don't mix jars/modules from different versions of a framework. Mixing 3.2 and 5.0 jars will lead to issues as well.

Comment: Yeah, I guess using a spring boot starter parent would be better.